# Typescript declaration issue with interface

Tags: typescript, declaration

I'm trying to declare an interface to allow a FormatComponent 'dictionary' to allow for a bunch of different components to be added - all implementing the interface.  This is a type lookup, not an instance, so I think I understand why I can't use the interface in Format Components below - only 'any' works.  There is a compiler error indicating the type doesn't implement data - when the interface is used.

But, it would be nicer to be type safe and use the interface in the declaration of FormatComponents - any ideas how to achieve it?

```
export interface FormatComponent {
    data: any;
}

export class ContactFormatComponent implements FormatComponent{
    data: any;
}

export const FormatComponents: { [id: string]: any } = {
    //I want FormatComponent instead of any
    'co-contacts': ContactFormatComponent,
    'other': OtherComponent // also implements the interface
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the type `{new(): FormatComponent}` to match a class (or rather, constructor) that implements `FormatComponent`.

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20FormatComponent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20ContactFormatComponent%20implements%20FormatComponent%7B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0Aexport%20class%20OtherComponent%20implements%20FormatComponent%7B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20const%20FormatComponents%3A%20%7B%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7Bnew()%3A%20FormatComponent%7D%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'co-contacts'%3A%20ContactFormatComponent%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'other'%3A%20OtherComponent%2C%20%2F%2F%20also%20implements%20the%20interface%0A%20%20%20%20'error'%3A%20String%0A%7D%3B)